# Как написать задание из егэ №8?

Tags: python

> Алексей составляет таблицу кодовых слов для передачи сообщений, каждому сообщению соответствует своё кодовое слово. В качестве кодовых слов Алексей использует 5-буквенные слова, в которых есть только буквы A, B, C, X, причём буква X может появиться на последнем месте или не появиться вовсе. Сколько различных кодовых слов может использовать Алексей?

Не могу понять как написать код, чтобы X могла не появиться в переборе слов.

Мой код.

```
   `from itertools import product
   k = 0
   for x in product('ABCX', repeat = 5):
       s = ''.join(x)
       if len(set(s)) and s[0]=='X':
           print(s, k)
       k+=1`
```

Comment: Генерировать кодовые слова не нужно, достаточно просто посчитать варианты

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А тебе точно надо *написать код*? Везде в интернете пишут что тебе надо *посчитать количество по формуле*, не?

Если все же нужен код... Просто для собственной пользы, попробуй ***понять*** что делает этот код:

```
from itertools import product
k = 0
for x in product('ABCX', repeat=5):
    if "X" not in x[:-1]: # [:-1] это такая штука которая отрезает последний символ
        k += 1
        print(x, k)
print(k)
```

Ответ 324?

Comment: Разобрался в чем разница?

Comment: Наверно, да. Во-первых я сделал преобразование списка в строку из-за этого не могу посчитать кол-во слов. Во-вторых забыл от существовании срезов. Вот и все.

Answer (score 6):

первые 4 буквы

```
>>> len(list(itertools.product('ABC', repeat = 4)))
81
```

на последнюю букву 4 варианта

```
>>> len(list(itertools.product('ABCX', repeat = 1)))
4
```

Умножаем 81*4 и

```
>>> 81*4
324
```

Варианты вывести можно

```
>>> for s1 in itertools.product('ABC', repeat = 4):
...     for s2 in itertools.product('ABCX', repeat = 1):
...         ''.join(s1+s2)
... 
'AAAAA'
'AAAAB'
'AAAAC'
'AAAAX'
....
'CCCCC'
'CCCCX'
```

### Но задача больше логическая

перемножить количество вариантов для каждой буквы

```
>>> 3*3*3*3*4
```

Answer (score 1):

Написать код, чтобы Х не появлялась в слове, можно вот так

```
for x in product('ABC', repeat = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
import itertools

s='АВСХ'
k=0
for i in itertools.product(s, repeat=5):
    a=''.join(i)
    if a[4]=='Х' and a[1]!='Х' and a[0]!='Х' and a[2]!='Х' and a[3]!='Х' or 'Х' not in a:
        k+=1 
print(k)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]